# How to find partners for a Bitcoin business?

Tags: services, business

Are there any resources available to find people who are interested in starting a Bitcoin-related business?

To answer comments:

I am looking for both partners who want to start a business and investors. Something related to bitcoin that is delivered via internet. Perhaps a stock exchange denominated in Bitcoin, algorithmic trading in Bitcoin, etc. I am open to many different ideas.

Comment: Generally a startup business will be a founder or pair of co-founders, until they have something to sell.   Or are you asking about "financial" partners / (investors)?

Comment: What sort of business are you starting and who do you need? I might be interested... ;)

Comment: @ThePiachu and - B Seven, I am open to new ventures as well.  I have a Butterfly Labs Mini Rig on order.  With custom mining software many things are possible.  Find me at my name at gmail.

Answer (score 5):

I think posting your ambitions here would return quite some feedback/interest:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=12.0

Comment: And this one: http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=20292.0